# If $TS=I$ then $ST=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose, $T:\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^3$ and $S:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^4$ be linear transformations such that $TS=I$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then, is it true that $ST=I$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$?

I think no. This is because, from $TS=I$, we obtain that $T$ is surjective and $S$ is injective that is, the kernel is zero. Then, by rank-nullity, the rank of $S$ must be full, that is, it must equal the dimension of its domain, which is $3$. Thus, the map $ST$ can have rank at most $3$, whereby implying that the map is not injective, hence not $I$. Since a linear operator from a vector space of finite dimension is injective iff it is surjective, $ST$ cannot be surjective? Is this true?  Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $\text{rank}(ST)\le\text{rank}(S)\le3$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng thanks, by the way, I my argument also right?

Comment: Your argument is correct. You already deduced that the rank is at most 3. The codomain of $ST$ is $\mathbb{R}^4$ which has dimension 4 so this means $ST$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: @vidyarthi The two arguments are basically the same, only one uses more words than the other.